How to resolve javax.persistence.PersistenceException with EntityManager named student_pu_test?
Title: "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager 'student_pu_test' in StudentRepository and StudentRepositoryTest Classes"
Body:
I am encountering a persistent issue with a javax.persistence.PersistenceException error in my Java application. The error message states "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named student_pu_test" and it points to the line where Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory() is called. Despite verifying my persistence.xml configuration, dependencies, and EntityManagerFactory setup, the problem persists.
I have two classes involved in this issue, StudentRepository and StudentRepositoryTest. Here are snippets of the relevant code:
StudentRepository Class:

package fr.charly.jPATutorial;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class StudentRepository {

    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public StudentRepository() { 
        this.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("student_pu_test");
        this.entityManager = this.emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public StudentRepository(String pu) {
        this.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(pu);
        this.entityManager = this.emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public Student add(Student student) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(student);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        return student;
    }

    public Student find(Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(Student.class, id);
    }

    public Student update(Student student) {
        Student studentToUpdate = find(student.getId());
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        studentToUpdate.setFirstName(student.getFirstName());
        studentToUpdate.setLastName(student.getLastName());
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        return studentToUpdate;
    }

    public void delete(Student student) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.remove(student);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void close() {
        this.entityManager.close();
        this.emf.close();
    }
}

StudentRepositoryTest Class:

package fr.charly.jPATutorial;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNull;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class StudentRepositoryTest {

    private static StudentRepository repository;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
        repository = new StudentRepository("student_pu_test");
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void afterClass() throws Exception {
        if (repository != null) {
            repository.close();
        }
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void add() {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setLastName("Red");
        student.setFirstName("Alan");

        repository.add(student);

        assertNotNull(student.getId());
        assertTrue(student.getId() != null);
    }

    @Test
    public void find() {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setLastName("Red");
        student.setFirstName("Alan");

        repository.add(student);

        student = repository.find(student.getId());

        assertNotNull(student);
        assertNotNull(student.getId());
        assertEquals("Red", student.getLastName());
    }

    @Test
    public void update() {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setLastName("Red");
        student.setFirstName("Alan");

        student = repository.add(student);

        student.setLastName("Green");
        student = repository.update(student);

        assertNotNull(student);
        assertEquals("Green", student.getLastName());
        assertEquals("Alan", student.getFirstName());
    }

    @Test
    public void delete() {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setLastName("Red");
        student.setFirstName("Alan");

        student = repository.add(student);

        repository.delete(student);

        student = repository.find(student.getId());

        assertNull(student);
    }
}

persistence.xml

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="student_pu_test"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>fr.charly.jPATutorial.Student</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:h2:mem:test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

Error message

juin 05, 2024 9:18:01 AM javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver log
AVERTISSEMENT: javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.111 s <<< FAILURE! -- in fr.charly.jPATutorial.StudentRepositoryTest
[ERROR] fr.charly.jPATutorial.StudentRepositoryTest -- Time elapsed: 0.111 s <<< ERROR!
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named student_pu_test
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at fr.charly.jPATutorial.StudentRepository.<init>(StudentRepository.java:18)
    at fr.charly.jPATutorial.StudentRepositoryTest.beforeClass(StudentRepositoryTest.java:20)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   StudentRepositoryTest.beforeClass:20 » Persistence No Persistence provider for EntityManager named student_pu_test
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.116 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-06-05T09:18:01+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.2.2:test (default-test) on project jPATutorial:
[ERROR]

[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Charly\Desktop\developpement\workspace\jPATutorial\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, and [date].dumpstream.

I've tried checking my configurations, looking for errors in the code, and checking online resources, but I haven't been able to resolve this issue yet.
I would greatly appreciate any ideas, suggestions, or solutions to help me troubleshoot and resolve this ongoing issue. Thank you in advance for your help and expertise.

Could you add the error logs? I guess this happens when you do a maven build.

It seems like you didn't add the file persistence.xml in the folder test/resources/META-INF. Have you done that?
And I think the subject of your post should be: "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named"
